# Colored PS1 string

Tags: bash, shell, ps1

**Clarification:** I want `__foo` to be executed each time the PS1 string is presented in the terminal, not when the PS1 string is constructed (hence its being in quotes). `__foo` contains logic that examines the current directory, so its execution must be deferred.

---

I'm trying to use different colours in my Bash PS1 string from within a Bash function:

```
LIGHTRED="\033[1;31m"
LIGHTGREEN="\033[1;32m"
RESET="\033[m"

__foo () {
    # Do some stuff and genereate a string to echo in different colours:
    echo -n '\['$1'\]firstcolour \['$2'\]secondcolour'
}

PS1='$(__foo '$LIGHTRED' '$LIGHTGREEN')\['$RESET'\] \$'
```

Essentially I want `__foo` to generate part of the PS1 in a bunch of different colours. My attempt doesn't seem to work, though; it produces the following output:

```
-bash: 31m: command not found
-bash: 32m: command not found
\[]firstcolour \[\]secondcolour $
```

What gives, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Bash environment variable **$PROMPT_COMMAND** to redefine the **$PS1** variable just before the prompt is displayed.

```
LIGHTRED='\033[1;31m'
LIGHTGREEN='\033[1;32m'
RESET='\033[m'

__foo () {
  # Do some stuff and genereate a string to echo in different colours:
  echo -n "\[$1\]firstcolour \[$2\]secondcolour"
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=$PROMPT_COMMAND'; PS1="$(__foo $RED $GRN)\[$RESET\]\n\$ "'
```

Note two additional changes that I have made to your code are optional here. They were added because I think it clarifies where/where not the escape codes get expanded:

- Hard quotes `'` around the color definition variables.
- Soft quotes `"` around the return string for `__foo`

Comment: What's the advantage of using `$PROMPT_COMMAND` to set `$PS1` instead of just having a dynamic `$PS1` string?

Comment: I think the quoting is easier using `PROMPT_COMMAND`; you don't need to create a string that runs a command every time it is evaluated; you just evaluate the dynamic parts and put the result in `PS1`.

Comment: @WillVousden -- Zero advantage. It is just an answer that will work. I provided this one because I guessed no one else would suggest solving the question with this approach.

Comment: Thanks; I wasn't aware of `$PROMPT_COMMAND`, so that's good to know!

Comment: I think you mean `$RESET` instead of `$OFF` in the last line.

Comment: @onlycparra -- I've now corrected the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `foo` returns a string which is executed by bash as a command, since you surrounded it with `$()` (and escaped all variable substitution with single quote marks.

Changing your code to this make it work just fine:

```
LIGHTRED="\033[1;31m"
LIGHTGREEN="\033[1;32m"
RESET="\033[m"

__foo () {
  # Do some stuff and genereate a string to echo in different colours:
  echo -n '\['$1'\]firstcolour \['$2'\]secondcolour'
}

PS1=$(__foo $LIGHTRED $LIGHTGREEN)\[$RESET\]\$
```

Comment: I should've been clearer in my question: I want `__foo` to be executed each time the PS1 string is presented at the terminal, not when the script is executed. I've updated my question. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it:

```
LIGHTRED="\033[1;31m"
LIGHTGREEN="\033[1;32m"
RESET="\033[m"

__foo () {
    # Do some stuff and genereate a string to echo in different colours:
    echo -n '\['$1'\]firstcolour \['$2'\]secondcolour'
}

PS1='$(__foo "'$LIGHTRED'" "'$LIGHTGREEN'")\['$RESET'\] \$'
```

The arguments to `__foo` needed to be enclosed in quotes.