# Bash PS1 string that evaluates certain code every time it is looked up

Tags: command-line, bash, string

This question is very similar to this one: [Colored PS1 string](https://superuser.com/questions/476307/colored-ps1-string)

But I still don't understand completely.

So say I have this function

```
function getjobs {
    echo $(jobs | wc -l)
}
```

And my PS1 is this

```
PS1="\u@\h: [jobs "
PS1="$PS1\$(if [[ $(getjobs) == 0 ]] ; then
               echo $(color $green);
            else
               echo $(color $red);
            fi)"
```

Now this only gets evaluated when .bashrc is loaded for the first time but what I want to have happen is this if statement evaluated every time a new prompt appears.

How can I do this?

EDIT: the `color` function returns escape sequences for those colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use something like this:

```
method_that_echos_values(){
    if [[ ]]; then
      echo -n "something"
    else
      echo -n "something else"
    fi
}

export PS1="\$(method_that_echoes_values)"
```

Note that getting it extracted to a method is required

Comment: When I did this, it printed out the escape sequence literally, I added a -e and that fixed that. Thanks!

Comment: One thing actually. Because I am using functions to format, the $? variable is getting set to the return value of those functions and my return value indicator is no longer functioning correctly. Is there some way I can store the old $? before my calls?

Answer (score 1):

I would use bash's PROMPT_COMMAND for this. See the [bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) man page and [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/557718/different-initial-bash-prompt/557793#557793) for an example.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: I find it easier to set PS1 explicitly in a function invoked through PROMPT_COMMAND than to figure what I have to echo and how to get the quoting right when setting PS1 to the output of a function. I don't know of any other difference.

Comment: I suppose that makes sense. I'll look into it. Thank you for your knowledge

Answer (score 0):

So I was doing more experimenting with different placement of different quotes and I found something that works, but if someone knows a cleaner, better solution, please let me know.

```
PS1="\u@\h: [jobs "
PS1="$PS1\$(if [[ "'$(getjobs)'" == 0 ]] ; then
           echo $(color $green);
        else
           echo $(color $red);
        fi)"
```

All I had to do was put the part that I want reevaluated in single quotes with everything else in double quotes. I didn't think that it'd work since I had a double quoted string next to a single quoted string but I guess that's an ok thing.